# How to deserialize using Thrit TBinaryProtocol

Tags: python-3.x, deserialization, thrift, thrift-protocol

I havea thrift file that was serialized with TBinaryProtocol.  I want to deserialize this file to read it's content.  What's the best approach to do it?

I am using thrift:

```
    from thrift.TSerialization import serialize
    from thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol import TBinaryProtocol
```

and then I defined the function:

```
def thrift_to_json(d):
    return serialize(d, protocol_factory=TBinaryProtocol())
```

When I run the above function I get this error msg:

```
TypeError: TBinaryProtocol.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'trans'
```

How can I pass the argument `trans` to the TBinaryProtocol?   and what is this `trans` argument?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The missing "trans" tells you that you need a **transport**, e.g. a file stream that holds the input data.

Thrift separates the endpoint transports (file, socket, http) from the serialization protocol (binary, json, compact) and that's why one needs at least as a minimum some "enpdoint" transport and some protocol.

Useful links:

- Python Tutorial: https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/py.html
- Python Library: https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/py/src